# $a\in\overline{S}$ if and only if there exists an $x_n\in S$ such that $|x_n-a|<\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

> Let $S$ be a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$and $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $a\in\overline{S}$ if and only if for each positive integer $n$,there exists an $x_n\in S$ such that $|x_n-a|<\frac{1}{n}$.

If there was  $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $|x_n-a|>\frac{1}{n}\forall n$
Then for $n>\mathbb{N}$and for$\epsilon>0$ $$|x_n-a|>\epsilon$$, then there exists the following open intervals $\mathscr{U}=(a-\frac{\epsilon}{2},a+\frac{\epsilon}{2})$ and $B=(x_n-\delta,x_n+\delta)$ for $0<\delta<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ such that $\mathscr{U}\cap B=\emptyset$ then $a\notin A'$ and $a \notin A$ which concludes $a\notin \overline{A}$.

So if $a\in \overline{A}$ then there must be a sequence that  $x_n\in S$ such that
$|x_n-a|<\frac{1}{n}$.

**Question**:

Is my proof right? If not. How should I prove the claim?

Comment: Which part you try to prove in your attempt this $\Leftarrow$ or  this $\Rightarrow$

Comment: @S.S.Danyal I tried to prove by contradiction. Admitting the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ does not converge to $a$.

Comment: Again which part

Comment: @S.S.Danyal Sorry but I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: @S.S.Danyal             I think it is part 2($\implies$). What do you think of my proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$"\Leftarrow"$ Take any $\epsilon>0$. (We neeed to see $S\cap (a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\neq \emptyset$.) Then there must be $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$ and $|x_n-a|<\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$. So $x_n \in S\cap (a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$.

$"\Rightarrow"$ $a\in \overline{S}$ means that $S\cap (a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\neq \emptyset$  for any $\epsilon>0$. For every $n>0$ say $\epsilon_n=\frac{1}{n}$, and choose some $x_n \in S\cap (a-\epsilon_n,a+\epsilon_n)$. Then we get a sequence $(x_n)$ and it has property what we want.

Addition: I am sorry your attempt can not work. For ex: $S=(0,3)$, $a=3$ and $x_n=1$ for all $n$. If you want to prove with contradiction you need to see for any sequence $(x_n)$ has not that property.